# Need help creating a percentage-based SASS grid system

Tags: css, sass

My maths is shocking & I cannot, for the life of me get this calculation to work. I am creating a CSS grid system that allows users to specify any number of grid columns (there are 12 by default), the gutter in between these columns, the maximum width around the columns & the margin inside that total width. The hopeful outcome is a percentage width for each column width & a percentage for the left margin of all columns.

If I use the defaults below, the max width will be 1200px, the inner margin on the left & right will be 20 giving an inner width of 1160 for the maximum allowed space for the grid. Does that make sense?

I'm using is SASS by the way. Look at the comments in the code to see what is currently working & not working.

**Here is the code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrmartineau/fMeBk/**

```
$gridColumnCount      : 12;   // Total column count
$gridGutterWidth      : 40;   // [in pixels]
$gridColumnPadding    : 30;   // [in pixels]
$gridMaxWidth         : 1200; // [in pixels]
$gridMargin           : 20;   // [in pixels] Space outside the grid

@function gridColumnWidth() {
    @return $gridMaxWidth / $gridColumnCount;
}
// Grid calculations
@function gridColumnWidthCalc($colNumber) {
    // Is correct
    @if $gridGutterWidth == 0 {
        @return percentage($colNumber / $gridColumnCount);
    }
    // Is incorrect
    @else $gridMargin > 0 {
        @return percentage( (($colNumber / $gridColumnCount) - gutterCalc(false) ) );
    }
}

@mixin columns($columnSpan: 1) {
    width: gridColumnWidthCalc($columnSpan);
}
@function gutterCalc($showUnit: true) {
    @if $showUnit == true {
        @return percentage( $gridGutterWidth / ( $gridMaxWidth - ($gridMargin * 2) ) );
    } @else {
        @return $gridGutterWidth / ( $gridMaxWidth - ($gridMargin * 2) ) * 100;
    }
}

@mixin gridColumn() {
    @if $gridGutterWidth > 0 {
        margin-left: gutterCalc();
    }
    @if $gridColumnPadding > 0 {
        padding: $gridColumnPadding + px;
    }
    float: left;
    min-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    clear: none;
    &:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    background-color: pink;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
@for $i from 1 to $gridColumnCount + 1 {
    .span#{$i}  { @include columns($i); }
}

.container {
    padding-left: $gridMargin + px;
    padding-right: $gridMargin + px;
    max-width: $gridMaxWidth + px;
}

.col {
    @include gridColumn();
}


​
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work, how does it not work, is there a difference, how much, etc....

Comment: The else conditional in gridColumnWidthCalc does not work. I have tried about 15 different variations & some are close but none are right. I need to provide a column number 1-12 in this case, & get a column width, in percent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, i spent an hour to comprehend your commentless code.

First of all, there's ambiguity between "columns" as grid units and "columns" as actual elements. Below i'm calling the latter "blocks".

You are correctly overriding gutter of the first block in a row. Thus, the total number of gutters is one less than the number of blocks in a row.

But when you're calculating block widths, you're subtracting gutter from every column without taking into consideration that there are less gutters than blocks.

So you should proportionally reduce the width of a block.

Working solution:

```
// Accepts a number of columns that a block should span.
// Returns a percentage width for that block.
@mixin columns($columnSpan: 1) {
    $number-of-blocks-in-container: $gridColumnCount / $columnSpan;
    $total-width-of-all-gutters:    gutterCalc(false) * ($number-of-blocks-in-container - 1);
    $total-width-of-all-blocks:     1 - $total-width-of-all-gutters;
    $width-of-a-single-block:       $total-width-of-all-blocks / $number-of-blocks-in-container;

    width:                          percentage( $width-of-a-single-block );
}
```

Now your wheel is rolling! See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/fMeBk/46/ Keep in mind that browsers round up percentage values with a slight error, so grid positioning might be not pixel-perfect. BTW, right-aligning the last block in a row is necessary to minimize the visual effect of this rounding error.

Dude, your code architecture is so wrong, and your approach has a number of drawbacks. I can name them if you want.

You really should give Susy another try. It is a brilliant piece of SASS and also a great source to learn SASS techniques from. Its source code is well commented and available on GitHub.

According to you, what features of your grid framework does Susy lack?

I assure you, Susy **can** do what you want. Just explain a task and i'll try to come up with an elegant solution leveraging Susy.

PS I'm not trying to dissuade you from experimenting. Practice makes perfect! Experimenting **is** necessary, and you're doing a great job. What i'm trying to tell is that you should follow a good example and adopt good practices so that you don't end up in the wrong place.

PPS Please give me back my rating. I devoted a lot of my personal time trying to help you, and you minused my answer. :(

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was something I hadn't thought of. Thank you for spending the time when I know you didn't need to. I will definitely look at Susy as an alternative. I have also seen [Zen grids](http://zengrids.com/) which look very interesting, have you seen them?

PS I cannot undo the rating thing without you editing your answer again for some reason. Do that & I'll happily change it.

Comment: Zen Grids position blocks independently, but you have to provide offset for each block. In Susy, blocks stack next to each other, only the last block in a container requires special treatment. You can't do `#container > * { @include span(2); }` with Zen Grids. Also, Zen Grids lacks Susy's scaffolding (a lot of extra mixins and functions that make your life easier). I've edited my previous answer. Good luck! :D

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state any specific question, and that's against StackOverflow rules.

And without your explainations of the structure of your framework, it's hard to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve with each function and mixin.

How are we supposed to help?

Anyway, you're approach is faulty for two reasons:

1. You're trying to re-invent the wheel. There are dozens of grid frameworks already.
2. You're using a non-semantic approach. You're styling by applying style-specific classes in HTML. Instead, your classes should be semantic (i. e. state the function of blocks, not their look) and styling should be applied to those classes in CSS. With SASS, it's very easy.

Solution: use [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/). It's a fantastic piece of software, and its author Eric Meyer is very responsive here on StackOverflow.

With Susy, your code could look like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="gallery">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div id="promos">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="bottom-menu"></div>
            <div id="partners"></div>
            <div id="social-buttons"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="col span12"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
//////////
// Imports
//////////

@import susy


//////////
// Defining variables
//////////

// Main grid properties
$total-columns  : 12      // Number of columns
$container-style: fluid   // The grid should stretch
$max-width      : 1200px  // But not wider than this

// Proportions between column width and gutter between columns
$column-width   : 85%     
$gutter-width   : 100% - $column-width

// Setting margins around the grid
$grid-padding   : 1em     // This will remain absolute
$container-width: 100%    // If you want relative margins, change this instead


//////////
// Applying containers and columns
//////////

// Setting containers in all immediate children of #container
#container > *
  +container /* ← Actual Susy magic! :D */
  max-width: $max-width

// Setting columns
#gallery > *
  +span-columns(1)
  &:last-child             // The last column should be marked with "omega"
    +span-columns(1 omega) // to compensate browsers' calculation errors

#promos > *
  +span-columns(2)
  &:last-child
    +span-columns(2 omega)

// #footer
#bottom-menu
  +span-columns(6)

#partners
  +span-columns(4)

#social-buttons
  +span-columns(2 omega)
```

Sorry, i haven't tested this code, it may contain errors, but you can still see the idea.

Susy also lets you easily create responsive grids. And they say Susy is gonna be the default grid engine in Compass.

UPD: See the question-specific answer next to this one!

Comment: You are right, I probably did not give enough information, it is much easier to show the framework rather than explain it, that is why I linked to a thorough example on jsfiddle. Have you seen it?

Comment: I am also not trying to reinvent the wheel but to add to it (if that makes any sense.. ), there are some other features in my framework that other grid frameworks do not have (btw, I have tried Susy & it is not what I'm looking for at this point), hence the need to get my calcs right. I am also using this as a SASS learning exercise having not used it before last week.

Comment: Then try to explain exactly what you want and exactly what you fail.

Comment: Quote from StackOverflow rules: "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed."

Answer (score 0):

I put together a simple SASS percentage based grid generator a little while back. The math that you're looking for is here:

https://github.com/jordancooperman/simple_grid/blob/master/assets/css/scss/partials/_grid.scss

Some of the css in there is for display purposes only so that you will see your grid if using the markup that's also included in the project. Let me know if you have any questions, cheers!